# JSESSIONID is getting recreated automatically after successful login

Tags: java, session, jsessionid

The requirement is JSESSIONID must be different before and after login.

The flow is login.jsp -> loginwebaction -> loginsuccess.jsp -> filter -> otheraction

my code is

1. after successful login (in loginwebaction),
2. copy all the attributes to a map from session,
3. invalidate the session,
4. recreate the session `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);`
5. copy all the attributes from map to new session,

Jsessionid changes after successful login and loginsuccess.jsp is displayed. but I have an issues.

After this, if I click any other link for some other action, it hits a filter. 
In filter, I have to check the session for user info if he has logged in, else error page must be displayed.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if(null == session.getAttribute("USER_INFO")){
    //redirect to error page
}
```

Problem is: The session accessed in the filter is new, no idea on how it is recreated. code in the filter is

Can any one help me on this, how to proceed further to rectify this session change?

Comment: When loginsuccess.jsp is displayed, does the browser http response header include the new or old JSessionid?  To see this, you might have to trace http messages or use browser debugging to view cookies/page source.  Maybe you need to manually set the new JSessionid header in the response?

Comment: Unable to reproduce error, kindly post source code and configuration details.

Comment: Have you checked if the Client has more than one Session Coockie - yes that can happen in some circumstances. You may also use a [Request Dump Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) to see the Request and Response exchanged between Client and Server. Another way may be to use a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to log whenever a Session is created / destroyed

Answer (score 1):

As I see, the problem in your code is:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

From [Servlet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29), `request.getSession()` creates a new session if there is no existing session. You need to change it to:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

This will make sure that it returns the existing session object (if valid) or returns null if there is no session.

To add little more, the following lines of code are effectively identical:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
//Overloaded getSession with 'true' boolean argument
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

Hope this helps.

If this doesnot fix your issue, the problem could be something else. Please add Skeleton code of your usecase so that I can give it a try.

Comment: I think that does not help. As giri wrote the session seen by the filter is new. Your suggestion would only return `null` if the filter is the one that creates the new session  - but at this point there should be an existing session.